# JPA how to call merge or persist

Tags: java, jpa

I'm new to JPA and I'm having a problem with this example code from a repository:

```
@Override
public boolean add(User user) {
    EntityManagerFactory emf = HibernateRepositoryFactory
            .getEntityManagerFactory();
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
    tx.begin();

    User tempUser = null;
    try {
        if (user.getId() != null) {
            tempUser = em.find(User.class, user.getId());
        }
        if (tempUser == null) {
            em.persist(user);
        } else {
            // if so, get the differences and persist them
            tempUser.setPassword(user.getPassword());
            tempUser.setUserName(user.getUserName());
            tempUser = em.merge(user);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logging.error("log error+ " :" + e);
    }
    tx.commit();
    em.close();
    emf.close();
    return true;
}
```

with entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")

public class User implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "ID", nullable = false, unique = true)
private Long id;

@Version
@Column(name = "OPTLOCK")
private int version;

@Column(name = "USERNAME", nullable = false)
private String userName;

@Column(name = "PASSWORD", nullable = false)
private String password;

public User() {
    super();
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public int getVersion() {
    return version;
}
```

}

I don't understand it completly.

In the line : if (user.getId() != null) user.getId will always be null because I believe the id will be generated at the moment the object will be persisted?  Like this the tempUser will never be filled in from the db and the object will always be persisted and not merged .... . Or do I see this wrong?

What will be the best way to see if you need to persist or merge like this.

Edit

what if I would use a main like this :

```
User user1 = new User();

    user1 .setPassword("password_user1");
    user1 .setUserName("userName_user1");

... .add(user1);
```

If I run this one time the User is added.  If I then run this again the User is again persisted with a id+1

Comment: Id may be not null if it is a detached entity that has been modified.

Comment: @Sjuan76  For as far as I see I don't see a detach.  If I make a main class with a User object I add with this method and I run it twice then 2 Users will be in my db and not one ... .

Comment: You only show a little of the program. The logic is using the code for updating an existing entity or persisting a new one. The former would be best done by retrieving the entity and detach it (so you do not hold a session for too long waiting for UI).

Comment: The last code snippet will _always_ persist a new user. If you were to load an existing user (that already has an id), and pass it to add(), then it would be updated not persisted as new user.

Comment: @zagyi Maybe I see it to simple, but the first time the object is persisted so it is in the db.  You say you need to "load"  a object and pass it, so I believe you say to see if the object you want to persist is a element in the db (based on some criteria) ... .  So this code will not work ... .

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you want to achieve. If you execute this code in different runs of the jvm, then it will create two users. If you call add() in the same run of main() with the same user instance, then the second call will update it, as the first call must have assigned an id to the new user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, if the user parameter is new (has never been persisted) then this method will `persist()` it. In case it's a detached instance (has already been persisted, and has an id), it will update it by calling `merge()`.

I think the method's name is misleading, it should rather be called `saveOrUpdate()`.

Comment: agreed.  This would be a better name

Comment: hmmm .. getid() is a method of the entity.  At the moment I create this object it will be null.  how can he see if the object is allready in the db without a call to the db.  Or do I see this wrong

Comment: If you set the user's id manually, and it happens to be an id of an existing user in db, then the method will update that existing user instead of creating a new one. There is nothing magical behind it that would distinguish such a hand-crafted user object from one that is a "genuine" detached entity.

Comment: but here the userid is autogenerated so if I would try to persist the same object (same password and Username) I would think he will not persist this

Answer (score 0):

If the method parameter User is a persisted entity then getId() will not be null.

Comment: how will he get this Id?  I call a method of the entity not a search to the db?

Comment: add method should be a method of a DAO or Repository class. Consider a case where I have loaded a User entity in another hibernate session in another method, then used that object to call this method, at this time the object is detached and the getId() call will not be null.

Comment: I tried this with just this entity and this method.  If I create a main methos that creates a new User Object with a password and username and I use this method to persit it.  the first time the User object is added, when I run the main again, the User is added again with a id+1 but all the rest the same??

Comment: in your main create a User object, then call add method with that object 2 times consecutively, debug step by step and observe the results, then my above comment will hopefully make sense.

Comment: I also think checking the PersistenceContexts part of the Hibernate Developer Guide would be a good idea. http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html_single/#d5e801[link]